# Klenke's proof of Slutzky's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

In Klenke's book on probability he states Slutzky's theorem as:

> Let $X, X_1, X_2, \ldots$ and $Y_1, Y_2\ldots$ be random varaibles with values in $E$. Assume $X_n \xrightarrow{\mathcal{D}} X$ and $d(X_n, Y_n) \xrightarrow{n\rightarrow \infty} 0$ in probability. Then $Y_n \xrightarrow{\mathcal{D}} X$.

Here $E$ is a metric space with metric $d$, and $\xrightarrow{\mathcal{D}}$ means convergence in disribution, i.e. $X_n \xrightarrow{\mathcal{D}} X$ if the distributions $\mu_{X_n}$ of the $X_n$ converge weakly to the distribution $\mu_X$ of $X$. By weak convergence he means
$$\int f \mu_{X_n} \rightarrow \int f \mu_X$$
for all continuous and bounded functions $f$.

His proof is as follows:

> Let $f: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be bounded and Lipschitz continuous with constant $K$. Then $$|f(x) - f(y)| \leq Kd(x,y) \wedge 2\|f\|_{\infty} \quad \text{for all } x, y \in E.$$ Dominated convergence yields $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbf{E}[|f(X_n) - f(Y_n)|] = 0.$ Hence we have $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} |\mathbf{E}[f(Y_n)] - \mathbf{E}[f(X)]| \\ \leq \limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} |\mathbf{E}[f(X)] - \mathbf{E}[f(X_n)]| + \limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} |\mathbf{E}[f(X_n)] - \mathbf{E}[f(Y_n)]| = 0.$$

I have a few questions about this proof:

1. Why are we only considering Lipschitz continuous functions? By the definition of weak convergence shouldn't we consider continuous and bounded functions instead?
2. What is the point of showing $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq Kd(x,y) \wedge 2\|f\|_{\infty}$? It appears we do not use it in the inequalities beneath it.
3. Why is he using $\limsup$ and not $\lim$ for the dominated convergence theorem? I thought this theorem only applies to $\lim$.
4. The above proof suggests there is a relationship between $X_n \xrightarrow{\mathcal{D}} X$ and $\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} |\mathbf{E}[f(X)] - \mathbf{E}[f(X_n)]| = 0$. What is this relationship?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me know if you need additional clarity on the following.

(1) Klenke proves weak convergence is equivalent to $\int f d\mu_n\to \int fd\mu$ for all $f$ Lipschitz and bounded (Portmanteau theorem).

(2) $E[|f(X_n)-f(Y_n)|]\leq E[Kd(X_n,Y_n)\wedge 2\|f\|_\infty]\to 0$ by dominated convergence (version with convergence in probability) since $d(X_n,Y_n)\to^P 0$ and $Kd(X_n,Y_n)\wedge 2\|f\|_\infty$ is bounded.

(3) If $\lim$ exists $\limsup$ exists and is equal to $\lim$. $\limsup$ is used in the next passage since we don't know if $\lim$ exists yet for $|E[f(Y_n)]-E[f(X)]|$.

(4) $\limsup_n|E[f(X_n)]-E[f(X)]|=0\iff \lim_nE[f(X_n)]=E[f(X)]$. For $f$ bounded Lipschitz, this is indeed one of the equivalent definitions of weak convergence in the setting of probability measures (just probability notation).

Comment: beat me by a second! (+1)

Comment: Thank you very much! So for (4) he is simply using a change of variables so the expectation is taken with respect to $\mu$ instead of $\mu_X$ or $\mu_{X_n}$ (as would be needed to show convergence in distribution)? Would you be able to explain how exactly the dominated convergence theorem is used here? If we don't know that $\lim$ exists, what justifies his statement that "by the dominated convergence theorem yields $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbf{E}[|f(X_n) - f(Y_n)|] = 0$"?

Comment: @CBBAM 

We have $E[f(X_n)]=\int f(x)\mu_{X_n}(dx)$, $E[f(X)]=\int f(x)\mu_{X}(dx)$ - this is the image measure integral in Ch. 4. Other question:


By dominated convergence we know that $\lim_nE[Kd(X_n,Y_n)\wedge 2\|f\|_\infty]=0$. Therefore, $\limsup_nE[Kd(X_n,Y_n)\wedge 2\|f\|_\infty]=0$ because $\lim=0$. Since $E[|f(X_n)-f(Y_n)|]\leq E[Kd(X_n,Y_n)\wedge 2\|f\|_\infty]$ for all $n$ we have $\limsup_nE[|f(X_n)-f(Y_n)|]\leq \limsup_nE[Kd(X_n,Y_n)\wedge 2\|f\|_\infty]=0$ ($\limsup$ always exists). But then, $\limsup_nE[|f(X_n)-f(Y_n)|]=0$ which implies $\lim_nE[|f(X_n)-f(Y_n)|]=0$.

Comment: @Snoop I understand now, thank you again for all the help!

Answer (score 5):

1. The subalgebra of Lipschitz functions is dense in $C_0(E)$, provided $E$ is locally compact. Convergence of distribution of $X_n$ can be tested using $\mathbb{E}f(X_n)$ for $f \in C_0(E)$.
2. You need this to apply dominated convergence, which is used immediately after the inequality is stated;
3. $0 \leq \mathbb{E}(|f(X_n) - f(X)|)$, so if $\limsup_n \mathbb{E}(|f(X_n) - f(X)|) =0$, it follows that $\lim_n \mathbb{E}(|f(X_n) - f(X)|) =0$; the author is choosing not to be presumptuous about the existence of this limit;
4. Provided your limsup holds for all $f \in C_b(E)$, they are equivalent

Comment: lmao we answered at the same time. (+1)